# How to add the float variables to a List<Point>?

Tags: c#, winforms

The code:

```
public static List<Point> Load()
{
    List<float> Points_X = new List<float>();
    List<float> Points_Y = new List<float>();
    int ImageWidth;
    int ImageHeight;
    double CurrentFactor;
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\Data";

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    file = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\Data" + "\\Data.txt";

    OptionsFile setting_file = new OptionsFile(file);
    Points_X = setting_file.GetListFloatKey("Points Coordinates X");
    Points_Y = setting_file.GetListFloatKey("Points Coordinates Y");
    ImageWidth = int.Parse(setting_file.GetKey("Image Width"));
    ImageHeight= int.Parse(setting_file.GetKey("Image Height"));
    CurrentFactor = double.Parse(setting_file.GetKey("Current Factor"));

    var points = new List<Point>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Points_X.Count; i++)
    {
        points.Add(Points_X[i], Points_Y[i]);
    }

    return points;
}
```

`points` is of type `List<Point>`. I want to add to this the `Points_X` and `Points_Y`. 
In the end points will look like for example in index 0:

```
{ X = 225 , Y = 122 }
```

I tried to use a `for` loop but its not the right way. How can I add to `points` the float variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you declaring points?

you need to declare

```
List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
```

then in loop if you have proper constructor

```
points.Add(new PointF(Points_X[i], Points_Y[i]));
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to add an instance of `Point` like:

```
points.Add(new Point(Points_X[i], Points_Y[i]));
```

instead of

```
points.Add(Points_X[i], Points_Y[i]); //error here
```

Probably its not a good idea to keep `X` and `Y` in two different `List<T>`, you should look into keeping a `List<Point>` from the beginning.

I believe you are looking for [`PointF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since you are storing floating point positions. Otherwise `Point` takes `int` positions.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you just need to create a new PointF and set it using your `Points_X` and `Points_Y` values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Points_X.Count; i++)
{
     points.Add(new PointF { X = Points_X[i], Y = Points_Y[i]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ Zip extension method:

```
Point[] newPoints = Points_X
    .Zip(Points_Y, (x, y) => new PointF(x, y))
    .ToArray();
points.AddRange(newPoints);
```

or if you are creating a new list anyway:

```
List<PointF> points = Points_X
    .Zip(Points_Y, (x, y) => new PointF(x, y))
    .ToList();
```

If you need a list of type `Point` instead of `PointF` you must convert the floats to ints:

```
(x, y) => new Point((int)Math.Round(x), (int)Math.Round(y)))
```

or just truncate

```
(x, y) => new Point((int)x, (int)y))
```